# d3: How to add border to a circle on an if-condition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am adding few circles to my d3 graph as below:

```
 this.node = this.svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'nodes')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('fill', (d) => { return this.color(d.group); })
    .on('click', this.mouseclick)
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on('start', this.dragstarted)
        .on('drag', this.dragged)
        .on('end', this.dragended));
```

Just like `d.group` used above, I have `d.error` present in my data which an either be `true` or `false`. How can I show a red border for the same node while its being appended (or later?) if `d.error === true`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a condition on this `d.error` and apply a `transparent` `stroke` if it's `false` and `red` otherwise:

```
.style("stroke", d => d.error ? "red" : "transparent")
```

Using `undefined` instead of `transparent` also does the trick:

```
.style("stroke", d => d.error ? "red" : undefined)
// which can also be written:
.style("stroke", d => { if (d.error) return  "red" })
```

Here is a demo:

```js
d3.select("svg").attr("width", 500).attr("height", 500)
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data([{ x: 85, y: 80, r: 35, error: true }, { x: 265, y: 124, r: 45, error: false }])
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")
    .attr("r", d => d.r)
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .style("stroke", d => d.error ? "red" : "transparent");
```

```html
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
<svg></svg>
```